# Impress <for> parameter by Inner code for next iterations in python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
for x in stem:
    stem[stem.index(x+1)] = "Four"
    print(x)
```

The problem begins when i design an algorithm (on paper) based on special (and strongly wrong) assumption and when i start coding in python, problem appears

Consider that `x` contains `["One" , "Two", "Three"]` at start moment (get from `stem`).

I want to impress `x` on for next iteration after first iteration. i want below result:

```
One
Four
Four
```

not this result which happens:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Comment: eidt your code to stem.index(x)+1

Comment: thanks, edited @AmeyYadav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stem = ["One" , "Two", "Three"]
#your code required a small edit
for x in stem:
    stem[stem.index(x)+1] = "Four"
    print(x)
```

But you can do the same thing using enumerate function too
Bascically this function takes an iterative object and allows you to loop with the elements and their indexes at the same time

```
stem = ["One" , "Two", "Three"]
for i, x in enumerate(stem):
    if i+1 < len(stem):
        stem[i+1] = "Four"
    print x
```

Answer (score 2):

Your index is wrong. Index finds the index of a string(`str`) and you are trying to add 1 to that. So move the `+1` outside of the parenthesis. It should be:

```
stem[stem.index(x)+1]
```

[Here](https://repl.it/IZZR/0) it is working.

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is x.